# how to include and link ieee80211_radiotap.h

Tags: c, linux, wifi

I want to add `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-32/include/net/ieee80211_radiotap.h` to my source code as `#include <ieee80211_radiotap.h>` (or ../ieee80211_radiotap.h). how do I do it? and how do I need to link it when I compile the code with `gcc`?

Comment: tried <net/ieee80211_radiotap.h>?

Comment: yes,I tried it, but it says, it does not have such file or directory, but "locate ieee80211_radiotap.h" shows the path I pasted in the question.

Comment: well i guess those headers aren't looked for in that dir you will have to add: -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-32/include

Comment: I did " gcc test.c -o test -l/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-32/include" but it stills output "No such file or directory". am I linking wrong?

Comment: if it is the linker that is giving you the error.. I don't know what the library that it is linking against... but you would specify it like: `-L/dir/to/Lib` and `-lsomeLib`